# Conditional append list for Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to attempt to filter our specific rows but I am getting an error that says:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(rdataset)
plane = 'axial'
contrast = 'T1'

a = []

for slices in range(0,60):
    if df['nSlices']==slices:  #---------------> Problem here ?
        path = df.loc[df['nSlices'].eq(slices) & df['Orient'].eq(plane)  & df['Contrast'].eq(contrast),'Path'].tolist()
        a.append(path)
```

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because you are  trying to compare Series object `df['nSlices']` with scalar integer `slices`. The result of such comparsion is Series object with bool values (try to do `print(df['nSlices']==slices)` to see it) and you can't use it in if-statement.

To solve the problem just remove `if df['nSlices']==slices:` to get:

```
for slices in range(0,60):
    path = df.loc[df['nSlices'].eq(slices) & df['Orient'].eq(plane)  & df['Contrast'].eq(contrast),'Path'].tolist()
    a.append(path)
```